# In Azure Blob container, How to delete all files by name under a directory?

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I use Azure blob client API, and I want to delete all files name "fieldA".
My diretory is as

```
/all/folder1/fieldA
/all/folder1/fieldB
/all/folder2/fieldA
/all/folder2/fieldC
```

After delete, I want it become

```
/all/folder1/fieldB
/all/folder2/fieldC
```

I do some search it says Azure blob container does not support regular expression search.
So I think the only way is to `list all blob` -> `filter fieldA` -> `delete`.

I wrote some code as following, and it keep give me unknow error. Could I know if there is sth not right?

```
 var ctoken = new BlobContinuationToken();

 do
    {
      var result = await blobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync('/all', true, BlobListingDetails.None, null, ctoken, null, null);
      ctoken = result.ContinuationToken;

      var a = result.Results.Where(item => (item as CloudBlob).Name.EndsWith("fieldA"));

       await Task.WhenAll(a
                   .Select(item => (item as CloudBlob)?.DeleteAsync())
                   .Where(task => task != null)
                );
     } while (ctoken != null);
```

Comment: Please include the error/exception you are getting. You are assigning `var a = ...` but it is never used. So your current code is likely to delete everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all files by name under a directory, please refer to the following code

My container is as below

```
container: test
blob :
/all/folder1/test.txt
/all/folder1/test1.txt
/all/folder2/test.txt
/all/folder2/test2.txt
```

[image]
[image]

Code

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string accountName = "andyprivate";
            string keyValue = "";
            string containerName = "test";
            StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentials(accountName, keyValue);
            CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri($"https://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{containerName}"), credentials);
         
            string prefix = "all/";
            await ListBlobsHierarchicalListingAsync(container, prefix);

        }

        private static async Task ListBlobsHierarchicalListingAsync(CloudBlobContainer container, string prefix)
        {
            BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
           
            do
            {
                BlobResultSegment resultSegment = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(prefix,
                    false, BlobListingDetails.Metadata, null, continuationToken, null, null);

                var a = resultSegment.Results.OfType<CloudBlob>().Where(item => item.Name.EndsWith("test.txt")).ToList();
                var b = resultSegment.Results.OfType<CloudBlobDirectory>().ToList();

                await Task.WhenAll(a
                   .Select(item => item?.DeleteAsync())
                   .Where(task => task != null));
                foreach (var r1 in b) {

                    Console.WriteLine("Virtual directory prefix: {0}", r1.Prefix);

                    await ListBlobsHierarchicalListingAsync(container, r1.Prefix);
                }
                continuationToken = resultSegment.ContinuationToken;

            } while (continuationToken != null);
        }
```

[image]
[image]